# python 3 don't recognize b of bytes-like object

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I'm using python 3.4 and I'm try to use the lib `pygraphviz`.

code (taken from pygraphviz):

```
def _run_prog(self, prog='nop', args=''):
"""Apply graphviz program to graph and return the result as a string.

>>> A = AGraph()
>>> s = A._run_prog() # doctest: +SKIP
>>> s = A._run_prog(prog='acyclic') # doctest: +SKIP

Use keyword args to add additional arguments to graphviz programs.
"""
    runprog = r'"%s"' % self._get_prog(prog)
    cmd = ' '.join([runprog, args])
    dotargs = shlex.split(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(dotargs,
                         shell=False,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         close_fds=False)
    (child_stdin,
     child_stdout,
     child_stderr) = (p.stdin, p.stdout, p.stderr)
    # Use threading to avoid blocking
    data = []
    errors = []
    threads = [PipeReader(data, child_stdout),
               PipeReader(errors, child_stderr)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    self.write(child_stdin)
    child_stdin.close()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    if not data:
        raise IOError(b"".join(errors))

    if len(errors) > 0:
        warnings.warn(b"".join(errors), RuntimeWarning)

    return b"".join(data)
```

when running I got this strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    g.draw(filename=args.out)
  File "/home/moshe/Desktop/boaz_matala_3_mivne/code/PcapViz-master/pcapviz/core.py", line 142, in draw
    graph.draw(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1474, in draw
    data = self._run_prog(prog, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1338, in _run_prog
    warnings.warn(b"".join(errors), RuntimeWarning)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

although I did used b to represent bytes-like object.

what am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: This seems to say you don't want bytes, you want a string.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Why do you use an empty bytearray `b""` to join errors and data? Are they bytearrays, too? If not, use an empty string `""` instead.

Comment: @DYZ yes. I'm confused because this code is taken from a lib, so it should be working and I don't get the problem here...

Comment: I am afraid you are using a Python 2 version of pygraphviz.

Comment: @DYZ how can I check my version?

Comment: Dunno. I would remove it and install a version that is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: @DYZ Okay. I'll try to see if this work for me now